# Want to add Multiprocessing in my Python code

Tags: python, web-crawler

This is my web crawling code and it works so far. However, I would like to improve crawling speed and realized will use Multiprocessing. I tried added some code to work Multiprocessing, but it has compile error.

This is my adding code regarding multiprocessing.

pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(crawling_1(), crawling_2()) // Probably I was wrong..

```
...
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(crawling_1(), crawling_2()) 
..
start_time = time.time()
..
  while version < 6:
    if version == 3:
       crawling_1()
       version += 1

       if version == 4:
          crawling_2()
          version += 1
save_excel()

def crawling_1():
    ...
    SearchUrl = f'https://myaddress/v{version}/search?page={pageNum}&q="{SearchKeyword1}"'
    driver.get(SearchUrl)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select('table.table.geekbench3-index > tbody > tr')
    for tr in table:
        temp_3 = [tr.select_one('.timestamp-to-local-min').text, tr.select_one('.model > a').text,
                  tr.select_one('.model > span').text]
        searchList_1.append(temp_3)
    pageNum += 1

def crawling_2():
    ...
    SearchUrl = f'https://myaddress/v{version}/search?page={pageNum}&q="{SearchKeyword1}"'
    driver.get(SearchUrl)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    total = soup.select('.list-col-inner')
    for i in total:
        temp_5 = [i.select_one('.timestamp-to-local-short').text, i.select_one('div.col-12.col-lg-4 > a').text,i.select_one('.list-col-model').text]
        searchList_2.append(temp_5)
    pageNum += 1

def save_excel():
    searchList = searchList_1 + searchList_2
    ...
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{unquote_plus(SearchKeyword1)}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{unquote_plus(SearchKeyword1)}')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: `pool.map(crawling_1(), crawling_2()) ` you don't call the function that you want to pass to `pool`. You just need to give it the function reference: `pool.map(crawling_1, crawling_2) `

Comment: @rdas You can use just one function at a time.

Comment: @rdas  (pool.map(crawling_1, crawling_2)), it has error as below --->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ken/PycharmProjects/my/venv/syntax_test.py", line 138, in <module>
    pool.map(crawling_1, crawling_2)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\my\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 475, in _map_async
    iterable = list(iterable)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @KlausD Do you mean pool.map(crawling_1) for my case?